# binding input parameter to a like clause in a cursor in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am trying to writing a PLSQL Procedure with an input parameter which will be assign to the like clause inside a cursor. BUt binding is not working properly. Please help me to solve it.

```
PROCEDURE SEARCH_DONOR (p_nic_ VARCHAR2,
                        records_ OUT Sys_Refcursor) 

  AS

  v_stmt_str      VARCHAR2(200);
  v_stmt_str2      VARCHAR2(4000);

  BEGIN

       OPEN  records_  FOR
      SELECT DONOR_ID_        Id,
             FIRST_NAME_      First_Name,
             LAST_NAME_       Last_Name,
             DOB_             Date_of_Birth,
             NIC_             NIC,
             CONTACT_NUMBER_  Contact_Number,
             BLOOD_TYPE_ID_   Blood_type

      FROM MOISLK_DONOR_INFO_TAB
      WHERE NIC like '%p_nic_%'
      AND CLIENT_STATUS_ = 0
      ORDER BY DONOR_ID_;

  END SEARCH_DONOR;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
WHERE NIC like '%' || p_nic_ || '%'
```

because you were searching for a string `p_nic`, while you want to search for a string that *contains* that parameter's value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response